# How to logging.debug with an operator?

Tags: python, logging, printing, operator-keyword

I've been trying to stop using print statements for my debugging and start using logging.debug.  I can use an operator in a print but logging doesn't seem to do the same.

For example this works

```
print('Is between now and then:    ', solar_noon < now < solarnoonplustimeunit )
```

and this this does not.

```
logger.debug('Is between now and then:    ', solar_noon < now < solarnoonplustimeunit )
```

The latter says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 471, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 335, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How should I do an operator test with logging?

Comment: The first argument is a format string. Try to add an `%s` at the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging module methods expects the first argument to be a format string, and the following args to belong to that format string: `logger.debug(fmt_str, arg1,....)`. But your string doesn't have any indication that more elements are coming after.

i.e. the logger.debug func is eventually going to try to do something like this:

```
fmt_str % (arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Try just adding the format str `%s`:

```
logger.debug('Is between now and then:    %s', solar_noon < now < solarnoonplustimeunit )
```

#### *Edit:* Why your original string works with `print`:

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
>
> Print objects to the stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and
>   written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end. Both sep
>   and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the
>   default values. If no objects are given, print() will just write end.

Since the default `sep` is a space, python's just mashing the string representation of your string and bool values together, separating them with spaces.

Comment: I'm guessing that Print assumes a string and prints it?

Comment: @Rich -- added an explanation of `print` behavior to my answer